# Facebook: how to parse access token string

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I request an access token from Facebook, it returns this as a string:

```
"access_token=AAABqLmGZAT7sBAJK8llYPWm27lgfRxVZBl************YQZDZD&expires=5182152"
```

How can I get the `access_token` portion from the above value in a new variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `parse_str()` for that:

```
parse_str('access_token=AAAAA***&expires=123', $a);
echo $a['access_token'];
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP?

```
$foo = $_GET['access_token'];
```

Depending on your setup, you'll also want to store the `expires` variable, so that you know how long the token is valid for.